# when to use move in function calls

Tags: c++, move-semantics, stdmove

I am currently learning more about all the c++11/14 features and wondering when to use std::move in function calls.

I know I should not use it when returning local variables, because this breaks return value optimisation, but I do not really understand where in function calls casting to a rvalue actually helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When a function accepts an *rvalue reference*, you have to provide an *rvalue* (either by having already a *prvalue*, or using `std::move` to create an *xvalue*). E.g.

```
void foo(std::string&& s);

std::string s;

foo(s);            // Compile-time error
foo(std::move(s)); // OK
foo(std::string{}) // OK
```

---

When a function accepts a *value*, you can use `std::move` to move-construct the function argument instead of copy-constructing. E.g.

```
void bar(std::string s);

std::string s;

bar(s);             // Copies into `s`
bar(std::move(s));  // Moves into `s`
```

---

When a function accepts a *forwarding reference*, you can use `std::move` to allows the function to move the object further down the call stack. E.g.

```
template <typename T>
void pipe(T&& x)
{
    sink(std::forward<T>(x));
}

std::string s;

pipe(s);             // `std::forward` will do nothing
pipe(std::move(s));  // `std::forward` will move
pipe(std::string{}); // `std::forward` will move
```

Comment: so when I do not need the variable anymore it makes sence to just use std::move?

Comment: @maxbachmann: in general, yes. But for things like primitive types, there's no benefit. And if the function you're calling takes a `const&`, there's no benefit as well.

Comment: why is there no benefit for primitive types?

Comment: @maxbachmann Because (a) there is nothing to move [moving is about indirect resources hidden behind pointers, mainly], and (b) there is no mechanism with which to move them [no move ctors!]

Comment: `bar(std::string{});` isn't a move, `s` is initialised from the expression

Comment: @Caleth: is that guaranteed even prior to 17?

Comment: [I think so](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init.list#1) `std::string{}` is a *direct-list-initialization* for `s`. It's certainly a prvalue

Comment: @Caleth: That was a direct initialisation from another `std::string` though. So, to perform the initialisation, the move ctor was invoked. It's not like you're passing a `"string literal"` or something else that triggers a different `std::string` ctor

Answer (score 9):

When you have some substantial object, and you're passing it as an argument to a function (e.g. an API, or a container `emplace` operation), and you will no longer need it at the callsite, so you want to *transfer ownership*, rather than copying then "immediately" losing the original. That's when you move it.

```
void StoreThing(std::vector<int> v);

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6/*,.....*/};
    StoreThing(v);
}

// Copies `v` then lets it go out of scope. Pointless!
```

versus:

```
void StoreThing(std::vector<int> v);

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6/*,.....*/};
    StoreThing(std::move(v));
}

// Better! We didn't need `v` in `main` any more...
```

This happens automatically when returning local variables, if RVO hasn't been applied (and note that such an "optimisation" is mandated since C++17 so you're right to say that adding a "redundant" `std::move` in that case can actually be harmful).

Also it's pointless to `std::move` if you're passing something really small (particularly a non-class thing which cannot possibly have a move constructor, let alone a meaningful one!) or you know you're passing into a function that accepts its arguments `const`-ly; in that case it's up to you as to whether you want to save the added source code distraction of a `std::move` that won't do anything: on the surface it's wise, but in a template you may not be so sure.

Comment: i dont understand "you want to transfer ownership rather than copying then "immediately" losing the original" is it "you want to transfer ownership rather than ( copying then "immediately" losing the original)" ? isnt moving for immediately losing the original?

Comment: @user463035818 Correct - this is indicated by the word tenses (and shown in the examples) but I'll clarify it with a comma.

Comment: yep, now I get what you mean with "immediately", together with the example it completely makes sense